# How to do the Whitney U test (wilcox.test) across several columns?

Tags: r, statistical-test

So I have data looking a little something like this:

Data:

| Area | Al | Cd | Cu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10000 | 0.2 | 30 |
| A | 15000 | 0.5 | 25 |
| A | NA | Na | NA |
| B | 8000 | 1.1 | 55 |
| B | 11000 | 0.2 | 40 |
| B | 13000 | 0.1 | 40 |

etc.

And I want to do a Mann Whitney U test between group A and B separately for each element/column.

I have managed to do this manually for each element individually according to this:

```
#Data is the above dataframe

Area_A <- subset(Data, Group %in% c("A"))
Area_B <- subset(Data, Group %in% c("B"))

WhitneyU_Al <- wilcox.test(Area_A$Al, Area_B$Al, na.rm = TRUE, paired = FALSE, exact = FALSE)
```

(I couldn't figure out how to do it based on the rows in the column "Areas" in one data frame, which is why I divided it into two subsets).

Now, I have a lot more columns than just these three (43 to be exact), and I was wondering if there was some way to do this across all columns without changing it manually each time?

I tried a few variations of this:

```
WhitneyU <- wilcox.test(Area_A, Area_B, na.rm = TRUE, paired = FALSE, exact = FALSE)

#OR

WhitneyU <- wilcox.test(Area_A[2:43], Area_B[2:43], na.rm = TRUE, paired = FALSE, exact = FALSE)
```

But they both return the error that "'x' must be numeric".

I suspect the answer isn't this easy and that I am barking up the wrong tree? Either that, or the question/answer is too obvious and I am just not seeing it.
When I tried looking up multiple tests most answers deal with how to do multiple tests if you have multiple "groups" (as in, they have area A, B, C and D). Sorry if this has been asked before and I didn't find it (or I didn't understand it). I did look.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
Upon request, using dput() on part of my data it looks a bit like this:

```
structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), Al = c(NA, NA, NA, 18100, 18400, 32500, 33200, 31200, 
17400, 13900, 14400), As = c(NA, NA, NA, 16.9, 14.6, 8.83, 8.59, 
8.42, 13.4, 13.5, 13.7), B = c(NA, NA, NA, 18, 16, 14, 14, 11, 
53, 87, 58), Bi = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.13, 0.12, 0.57, 0.55, 0.52, 0.22, 
0.18, 0.21), Ca = c(NA, NA, NA, 5950, 5480, 6220, 6230, 5950, 
6850, 8170, 7000), Cd = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.18, 
0.31, 0.36, 0.46)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wilcox.test` requires the first input (x) to be numeric. In R, factors have an integer value assigned to them “under the hood” (ie, A = 1, B = 2,…). So you can convert the group variable in your data frame `df`. This should work to perform the test across all other columns:

```
df$Group <- as.factor(df$Group)

lapply(df[-1], function(x){
    wilcox.test(x ~ df$Group)
})
```

Comment: @sleeplessphd see the edit - convert the group into a factor first and it should run. It did on the structure you provided. Let me know if it works in your full data!

Comment: To be more detailed, your group column is a character (not factor like I thought) so the error was from trying to convert a character to numeric - all your values were NA. You can see the structure of your data with `str(df)`

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I got the code to work, but it did the wrong thing. (It compared each Element column in it's entirety to the now-numbered group columns  instead of comparing the Elements in Group A to the Elements in Group B within the column (don't know if that makes sense).). However, I did manage to solve the problem anyways. Thank you for helping me along the way.

Comment: Now it works perfectly (and is much smoother than what I managed to cobble together). Thank you!